# when I try to update the values in table I get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}(id=1)"

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

In spring boot using Jsp, I have created a Employee management System where we can add,update and delete employee. but the problem is when I try to update the values in table I get NumberFormatException error. I couldn't add Employee Details also so, I had fetch values into table from database. the problem is in DAO.Class where I should do some changes. I've tried many ways but nothing works for me. so, please give me a solution for this problem.

EmployeeDao class

```
package net.javaguides.ems.controller;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.javaguides.ems.entity.Employee;

@Service()
public class EmployeeDao 
{
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    

    /*
     * public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) { this.jdbcTemplate =
     * jdbcTemplate; }
     */
     

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees()
    {
        //List<Map<String,String>> data  = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        
        
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from employee", new RowMapper<Employee>()
                {
                    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException
                    {
                        Employee emp = new Employee();
                
                
                         emp.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                          emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                          emp.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
                          emp.setEmail(rs.getString("email")); 
                          emp.setGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                          emp.setMarriage(rs.getString("marriage"));
                          emp.setBirthday(rs.getDate("birthday"));
                          emp.setWorkat(rs.getString("workat"));
                          emp.setDepartment(rs.getString("department"));
                  
                  
                  return emp;
                 
                    }
                });
    }
    
    public long saveEmployee(Employee p)
    {
        
        /*
         * SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
         * System.out.println("DOB ::"+p.getBirthday()+"::"+format1.format(p.getBirthday
         * ()));
         */
        
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          format1.format(p.getBirthday());
            
            /*
             * String sql
             * ="insert into emsystem.employee(id,birthday,department,email,first_name,gender,last_name"
             * + ",marriage,workat) values" + " ('"+p.getFirstName()+"','1','2021-08-06'" +
             * ",'"+p.getDepartment()+"','"+p.getEmail()+"','"+p.getLastName()+"'," +
             * "'"+p.getGender()+"','"+p.getLastName()+"','"+p.getMarriage()+"','"+p.
             * getWorkat()+"');";
             */
             
         
                
                
                  
          String  sql="insert into employee(id,firstName,lastName,email,gender,marriage,birthday,workat,department) values "
                  +
                  "('"+p.getId()+"',"+p.getFirstName()+","+p.getLastName()+","+p.getEmail()+","+p.getGender()
                  +","+p.getMarriage()+","+p.getBirthday()+","+p.getWorkat()+",'"+p.getDepartment()+"')"; 
                  System.out.println("SQL ::"+sql);
                 
                  return jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
                 
                 
              
                // return jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
        
    }
    
    //@Deprecated
    public Employee getEmployeeById(Long id)
    {
        String sql="select * from employee where id=?";  
        
        //return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from employee where id=?",new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class), new Object[]{id});    
        
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class),new Object[]{id});    
    }
    
    public long updateEmployee(Employee p)
    {
        String sql="update employee set firstName='"+p.getFirstName()+"', lastName="+p.getLastName()+",email="+p.getEmail()+",gender="+p.getGender()+",marriage="+p.getMarriage()+",birthday="+p.getBirthday()+",workat="+p.getWorkat()+",department='"+p.getDepartment()+"' where id="+p.getId()+"";    
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql); 
    }
    
    public long deleteEmployeeById(Long id)
    {
        String sql="delete from employee where id="+id+"";    
        return jdbcTemplate.update(sql);   
    }
}
```

Error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jul 11 11:01:50 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}(id=1)"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}(id=1)"
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{id}(id=1)"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:714)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:125)
    ... 47 more
```

Controller

```
package net.javaguides.ems.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;


import net.javaguides.ems.entity.Employee;

@Controller // Controller Layer holds all Spring MVC Controllers
public class EmployeeController {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;
    

    /*
     * @GetMapping("/") //from this method will call findPaginated method -> this
     * will return paginated Employees. public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
     * return findPaginated(1, model); }
     */


    //handler method to handle list employees and return mode and view
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public String listEmployees(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("employees", employeeDao.getAllEmployees());
        return "employees";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/employees/new")
    public String createEmployeeForm(Model model)
    {
        //Create empty employee object to hold employee form data
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "create_employee";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, 
            BindingResult bindingResult)
    {                                       
        //Here, we r using ModelAttribute to directly bind form data to the employee object.
        
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "create_employee";
        }
        else
        {
            employeeDao.saveEmployee(employee);
            return "redirect:/employees";
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/employees/edit/{id}")
    public String editEmployeeForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) //PathVariable Annotation is to get the id.
    {
        model.addAttribute("employee", employeeDao.getEmployeeById(id));
        return "edit_employee";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public String updateEmployee(@PathVariable Long id,
            @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
    {
        
        
        // save updated employee object
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "create_employee";
        }
        else
        {
            // get employee from database by id
            Employee existingEmployee = employeeDao.getEmployeeById(id);
            existingEmployee.setId(id);
            existingEmployee.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
            existingEmployee.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
            existingEmployee.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
            existingEmployee.setGender(employee.getGender());
            existingEmployee.setMarriage(employee.getMarriage());
            existingEmployee.setBirthday(employee.getBirthday());
            existingEmployee.setWorkat(employee.getWorkat());
            existingEmployee.setDepartment(employee.getDepartment());
            
            employeeDao.updateEmployee(existingEmployee);
            return "redirect:/employees";
        }
        
    }
    
    // handler method to handle delete employee request
    
    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        employeeDao.deleteEmployeeById(id);
        return "redirect:/employees";
    }
}
```

DB configuration

```
package net.javaguides.ems;



import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Autowired 
    private Environment env;
    
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        //DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));//this.dbDriver
        datasource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));//this.dbURL
        datasource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));//this.dbUserName
        datasource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));//this.dbPassword
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    /*
     * @Bean("resourceBundle") public ResourceBundle resourceBundle() {
     * ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("query"); return rb; }
     */
}
```

Comment: Looking at the exception, the problem appears to be when Spring MVC is trying to call your controller. Can you share the controller’s code and details of the HTTP request that you are sending to it?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson please, check the code again. I've added Controller class and DBconfiguration class.

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t included the URL that you are using to make the request, but, having seen your controller’s code, I think that’s the problem.

Judging by the error message, you are making a GET request to something like `/employees/{id}(id=1)`. Your `@GetMapping` is `/employees/{id}` so everything after the second `/` becomes the value of `id`. Due to you use of `@PathVariable`, Spring MVC tries to convert `"{id}(id=1)"` to a `Long` for your `id` argument and it fails.

If my assumption about the URL to which you are making the request is correct, you can fix the problem by changing the URL that you’re using. Assuming that the employee’s ID is 1, it should be `/employees/1`.

Comment: my url for getting request is localhost:8080/employees

Comment: Are you sure? If that were the case, there would be no String to Long conversion involved. The `{id}(id=1)` input must be coming from the request.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you pass a parameter using the URL directly, for example

```
/employees/1
```

you are passing a String, whetever you like it or not. So the best solution would be

(this is one of the controllers, similar solutions applies to the others)

```
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable String id)
{
    try {
    Long longid = Long.valueOf(id);
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Exception Handling here (maybe an error page, idk)
    }
    employeeDao.deleteEmployeeById(longid);
    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```

Plus, I strongly recommend you to use custom repository, so you don't need to create standard queries like insertion, deletion, and standard selection everytime (look for [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) or [JpaRepository](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa))

Comment: Spring MVC will happily convert the string `”1”` into the number `1` for you, there’s no need to write code to do so.

Comment: I used this approach for some project, it is expecially good for exception handling, since you can throw custom exception, instead of MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException, which is usually pretty generic

Comment: That’s fine but it isn’t necessary in this case and won’t solve the problem of the `String` being something that cannot be converted into a `Long`